# Import/read UIFileSharingEnabled

Tags: ios, swift, sharing

I work with Xcode 7 and IOS 9.

I want to know how to read the file shared with iTunes (UIFileSharingEnabled).

I managed to share a file (Export) but I can not read a file is added by user ...

Thank you in advance !

**UPDATE :**
I managed to add my files, but can not access ay since my swift code.
When I try to retrieve the bundle, he referred me nil

```
let strBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DictionaryContents", withExtension: "cvs") // return nil
```

[image]

Comment: Update your question with details about what you have done or tried and what issues you are having.

Comment: Start by reading [File-sharing Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30)

Comment: @hugo you type cvs instead of csv

Comment: But the problem is that you need to append the file name to the documents folder url to locate that file